# How can i get whole date and time data when using cachedrowset from Oracle date field

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, timestamp, cachedrowset

I get data from oracle with result set and then populate them to `cachedrowset`. But when I get a date field in database and print it, it only print the date. I check the api and know that the `getDate()` method return `java.sql.date`,and time of `sql.date` is casted to 0. I test that if I call `resultset.getString("datefield")`, it can get whole date and time data, so is there any way to get whole date and time data using `cahcedrowset`, thanks

here's my source code

```
    CachedRowSet rs = null;
    try {
    rs = executeQuery("select * from t_web_order_result ");
    if (rs != null && rs.next()) {
            KKLog.info(rs.getDate("stime"));//2012-04-24,it should be 2012-04-24 09:23:33
        KKLog.info(rs.getString("stime"));
    }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        logErr("queryCheckers Err", e);
    } finally {
        closeCachedRowset(rs);
    }
```

executeQuery method

```
    CachedRowSet rowset = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        connection = getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i ++) {
            statement.setObject(i + 1, params[i]);
        }
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        rowset = new CachedRowSetImpl();
        rowset.populate(rs);
        rs.close();
        statement.close();
    } finally {
         //close....            
    }
    return rowset;
```

i used three method to print the log

```
    KKLog.info(rs.getDate("stime"));
    KKLog.info(rs.getString("stime"));
    KKLog.info(rs.getTimestamp("stime"));
```

and the log content is

```
    12-11-11 17:06:11 2012-04-24 
    12-11-11 17:06:11 2012-04-24 
    12-11-11 17:06:11 2012-04-24 00:00:00.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the date and time from database, you have to use

```
KKLog.info(rs.getTimestamp("stime"))
```

This will give both date and time from table provided date and time is stored as `date` data type or as `timestamp` .
Also note that you have to use `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`.

**Update 1**

There are some [bugs](http://www.blogjava.net/bing/archive/2009/12/09/jdbc_V8Compatible_timestamp_number_error_problem.html) associated with getting time part from database if cachedrowset is used.

I tried using CachedRowSet and time part was missing. In order to resolve this issue, add the following in the database connection part. I could see the time part as well.

```
    java.util.Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
    prop.put("oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible", "true"); 
    prop.put("user", "user");
    prop.put("password", "password");
   Connection conn = 
  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:port:SID",prop);
```

Adding 
`prop.put("oracle.jdbc.V8Compatible", "true");`  is the key in resolving this issue.

My date and time before

```
2012-11-08 00:00:00
```

After adding `V8Compatible`

```
2012-11-08 13:28:35
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, i used like that, but it prints 2012-04-24 00:00:00.0

Comment: @Jadic And by the way which driver do you use?

Comment: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver, and i use ojdbc14.jar

Comment: @Jadic I have updated my answer, please have a look and hope this would resolve the issue.

Comment: i accepted your answer, but my reputation is not enough to vote up :-)